# Prove a logical formula is equivalent to the contradiction if and only if the set it describes is empty

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, formal-theory, set-theory

Let `ψ` be a [well-formed-formula (wff)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula). Prove that

```
(ψ ≡ ⊥) ⇔ {x:ψ(x)}=Ø
```

that is, the formula `ψ` is a [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) if and only if the set it describes has no members.

**Note** This question is not about understanding why this is true. The idea seems intuitively simple: If `ψ` is a contradiction, then it is false and no element `x` in set theory can possibly satisfy it. That is, `ψ(x)` is false for any `x`. So the set `{x:ψ(x)}` has no members, i.e. is equal to the empty set `Ø`. The other direction is also not hard to understand (if `{x:ψ(x)}=Ø`, then no set `x` satisfies `ψ`, so `ψ(x)` must be false for any `x`, and so it makes sense that `ψ` is a contradiction.)

My question is, how could one prove this formally (that is, formalize my argument not in terms of loose English sentences like I have provided, but in strict formal logic?) Please note my knowledge of logic and structure is very limited apart from introductory set theory and the ZFC axioms. But I am trying to formalize my basic understanding of logic similar to how ZFC formalized set theory for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: From the way you are using ψ it seems to be a 1-place predicate, if so it can not be a contradiction, only a closed (e.g. fully quantified) formula can be that. So by "ψ is a contradiction" you probably mean ∃xψ(x) is a contradiction, i.e. ψ(x) is false for any value of x. Then formal proof will depend on the precise form of the definition of empty set, one definition is Ø:={x:x≠x}. But by assumption ψ(x) and x≠x have the same truth value on any x, so by the extensionality axiom {x:ψ(x)}=Ø.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to remember that :

> **a ∈ {x:ψ(x)} ⇔ ψ(a)**

(this is the definition of the "set-builder" symbol **{ _ : __ }** ).

But **{x:ψ(x)} = Ø**, and thus :

> for all **a, a ∉ {x:ψ(x)} ⇔** for all **a, ¬ψ(a)**.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. That's exactly what I was looking for. I had never seen the statement `a∈{x:ψ(x)} ⇔ ψ(a)`, how come this isn't explicitly taken as an axiom in ZFC? Do you recommend any books that elaborate on this topic?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree - see e.g Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA34) (1960 - Dover reprint), page 34 : it is not an axiom of ZFC but a general definition of an "operator" (the *set-builder*) used in any set theory,

Answer (score 1):

@EthanAlvaree I assume that you consider *psi* an unary predicate. And that your statement *psi equivalent false* means: *For all x: psi(x) is false*.

If that's what you mean, then nearly by definition:

*psi equivalent false* if and only if *The set of all x, which satisfy psi, is empty.*